# PHP require_once error with relative path

Tags: php, path, phpunit, relative-path, require-once

I would like to test my php application in phpunit. My problem is the require_once doesn't find the file what I would like to test. I get this error:

```
Warning:
require_once(C:\MyProject\phpunit-tesztek\include/../include/form.php):
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
C:\MyProject\phpunit-tesztek\include\FormTest.php on line 4
```

So it search the form.php file in include/../include/form.php  what is wrong.

I used this code:

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
require_once(__DIR__.'/../include/form.php');
```

the Test file is in C:\MyProject\phpunit-tesztek\include\FormTest.php

and the file what I want to test is in: C:\MyProject\include\form.php

What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the path you want to required ("`C:\MyProject\include\form.php"`) does not match the path you specify: "`C:\MyProject\phpunit-tesztek\include/../include/form.php`". It should become clear from the error message, can you see it? See as well the [answer by Steven Scott](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19140099/367456).

Comment: Please share why you were not able to select an answer so far. Is there anything not clear how to solve this? Please let us know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the relative path.  The `__DIR__` uses the directory the file is in without a trailing separator. You are then changing the path with a relative path (`/../`) to go up one directory.

See the manual entry -> [PHP Manual for `__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

```
__DIR__ will return C:\MyProject\phpunit-tesztek\include
```

You are looking to use the `C:\MyProject\include\` path

```
__DIR__ . '/../../include/Form.php';
```

I normally use the `dirname(__FILE__)` myself, as it gets the current directory of the source code file (which is absolute) allowing my relative path to move from that location.

Comment: `dirname(__FILE__)` is the outdated way to write exactly `__DIR__` which was introduced in PHP 5.3 and not available earlier. It btw. was introduced to spare `dirname()` calls. Just FYI :)

Comment: @hakre Thanks for the FYI.  I have references to the old, as 5.2 was still in use in areas, and for some of the team, it is a little clearer that you are getting the directory of what is passed.  While __DIR__ is the script's directory, you can use dirname() on another variable to retrieve its path as well.\

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `../`

`require_once(DIR.'include/form.php');`

Answer (score 0):

Use magic constant **DIR** :

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../include/form.php');
```

Comment: sorry, seems like SO text parser issue